# Is there a place in Gemarra or Chazal that describes or recommends using Memory Palaces?

Tags: talmud-gemara, chazal

I have read that a number of ancient philosophers, western and eastern, describe the use of [Memory Palaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_loci) as an aid to memory.

Is there also a place in Chazal with such a recommendation or description?

Comment: Try asking Joshua Foer

Comment: @DoubleAA Great idea. I emailed him. But if this community has ideas, that would be great.

Comment: Tosefta Sotah 7:12 עשה לבך חדרי חדרים והכניס בו דברי ב"ש ודברי ב"ה דברי המטמאין ודברי המטהרין... this could be interpreted as referring to utilizing a memory palace according to Shlomo Naeh, as reported in Stories of the Babylonian Talmud (pp. 108-109).

Comment: @Deuteronomy Thanks! That is great. I used it. I was unable to trace back to the footnote referencing "Naeh, 'Make Yourself Many Rooms'" as the source seems to be in Hebrew, and though I may be _almost_ able to read it, I don't know how to find such a text on the internet.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Also, the source in Tosefta Sotah, at least on Sefaria, is in 7:7, not 7:12, it appears to me.

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica the reference is to עשה לבך חדרי חדרים: עיון נוסף בדברי חז"ל על המחלוקות",מחויבות יהודית
מתחדשת: על עולמו והגותו של דוד הרטמן, בעריכת צ' זוהר וא' שגיא, תל אביב
תשס"א, עמ'875-851 Perhaps if you email Pof. Naeh requesting a copy he'll oblige: shlomo.naeh@mail.huji.ac.il